# why rsa public key is number but public key is alphabet?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, public-key, key-pair

When I check a `.crt` file, I see:

```
$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -text

//bla bla bla
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9a:b4:f0:e7:15:58:9d:3c:1a:46:45:24:2d:e8:
                    3a:2a:4b:5c:1a:2d:7f:9a:0b:28:e5:d3:cb:0d:c7:
                    a4:a4:fd:4b:4e:94:c7:dd:f0:8f:14:e5:78:c7:27:
                    a7:9a:c9:4e:6f:a9:fb:9a:68:fe:54:7e:d0:a3:69:
                    de:00:2d:7c:5d:93:87:e6:17:2a:bd:93:bb:2c:34:
                    b1:cf:23:a5:44:d2:ab:2a:e3:72:71:24:a7:cb:32:
                    b3:f7:9d:85:66:4b:d6:72:2a:e3:25:fc:c8:06:8a:
                    a1:ea:a5:65:e8:75:7d:89:3e:cd:90:24:4c:48:da:
                    a4:f5:ea:ba:b4:af:ee:55:18:b4:95:8b:00:74:98:
                    a0:00:45:57:83:4e:f5:23:9f:e1:f0:5b:47:5f:a7:
                    99:40:55:75:10:fd:c9:b3:b1:5e:17:43:b4:86:b1:
                    0f:95:5f:b0:50:45:f2:6d:7c:63:96:1d:ba:2c:97:
                    73:87:4d:54:fb:8a:72:5e:da:ea:e1:37:33:aa:ce:
                    a2:3f:07:f8:f7:96:3e:f0:c7:5e:c4:10:c7:40:0a:
                    8a:52:1b:27:0e:46:d5:7e:04:49:f4:1d:25:0a:af:
                    6a:4d:46:3c:ff:06:40:84:4e:f6:c6:af:8b:b0:0d:
                    c7:48:68:1f:ed:c9:df:13:e7:ad:7e:55:35:06:ad:
                    3a:05
```

which shows an RSA public-key is numbered, but, when I check the same file for public-key, it shows an alphabet key:

```
$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -pubkey -noout

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmrTw5xVYnTwaRkUkLeg6
KktcGi1/mgso5dPLDcekpP1LTpTH3fCPFOV4xyenmslOb6n7mmj+VH7Qo2neAC18
XZOH5hcqvZO7LDSxzyOlRNKrKuNycSSnyzKz952FZkvWcirjJfzIBoqh6qVl6HV9
iT7NkCRMSNqk9eq6tK/uVRi0lYsAdJigAEVXg071I5/h8FtHX6eZQFV1EP3Js7Fe
F0O0hrEPlV+wUEXybXxjlh26LJdzh01U+4pyXtrq4Tczqs6iPwf495Y+8MdexBDH
QAqKUhsnDkbVfgRJ9B0lCq9qTUY8/wZAhE72xq+LsA3HSGgf7cnfE+etflU1Bq06
BQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Why is one of them a hexadecimal number while the other same key is an alphabet?

(Note: I've created a self-signed key, if it helps.)

Comment: Because it has been hex-encoded for display.

Comment: @user207421 I thought about that, but the first number in the hex series is `00`, and the first character is `M`. It's not ascii.

Comment: It's base64 encoded.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks a lot. Please post it so that I can submit it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is one of them a hexadecimal number while the other same key is an alphabet?

For the same reason that apples and oranges don't taste the same.

> $ openssl x509 -in server.crt -text

This is showing the properties of a certificate in a human readable format.  That includes providing a textual description of the algorithm, key size, and then the hex value for the RSA modulus.

> $ openssl x509 -in server.crt -pubkey -noout

This is producing a PEM-encoded X.509 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` value.  It's intended to be read by machines, not humans.  If you want to see the same information, run that through `openssl pkey -pubin -text -noout`, e.g.

```
$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -text -noout
RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
Modulus:
    00:9a:b4:f0:e7:15:58:9d:3c:1a:46:45:24:2d:e8:
    3a:2a:4b:5c:1a:2d:7f:9a:0b:28:e5:d3:cb:0d:c7:
    a4:a4:fd:4b:4e:94:c7:dd:f0:8f:14:e5:78:c7:27:
    a7:9a:c9:4e:6f:a9:fb:9a:68:fe:54:7e:d0:a3:69:
    de:00:2d:7c:5d:93:87:e6:17:2a:bd:93:bb:2c:34:
    b1:cf:23:a5:44:d2:ab:2a:e3:72:71:24:a7:cb:32:
    b3:f7:9d:85:66:4b:d6:72:2a:e3:25:fc:c8:06:8a:
    a1:ea:a5:65:e8:75:7d:89:3e:cd:90:24:4c:48:da:
    a4:f5:ea:ba:b4:af:ee:55:18:b4:95:8b:00:74:98:
    a0:00:45:57:83:4e:f5:23:9f:e1:f0:5b:47:5f:a7:
    99:40:55:75:10:fd:c9:b3:b1:5e:17:43:b4:86:b1:
    0f:95:5f:b0:50:45:f2:6d:7c:63:96:1d:ba:2c:97:
    73:87:4d:54:fb:8a:72:5e:da:ea:e1:37:33:aa:ce:
    a2:3f:07:f8:f7:96:3e:f0:c7:5e:c4:10:c7:40:0a:
    8a:52:1b:27:0e:46:d5:7e:04:49:f4:1d:25:0a:af:
    6a:4d:46:3c:ff:06:40:84:4e:f6:c6:af:8b:b0:0d:
    c7:48:68:1f:ed:c9:df:13:e7:ad:7e:55:35:06:ad:
    3a:05
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

as that command reads the PEM-encoded X.509 `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` blob and turns it into a human-readable form (with some slightly different presentation, since it skips labeling the algorithm).